# my code not refresh screen after close and open application again

Tags: android

this is my code below which run perfectly first time when code run is show current week see this image show perfectly today is sunday 28 jully  is show perfectly see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Au9c.jpg    when i move to see previous week see tis img http://imgur.com/Rvf8QYp is show perfectly  when i close application and start again  is again show this last week screen  not current week screen . its mean its maintain last state how i refresh calender every time when application start?? below is my complete code

```
    public class HoyahCalendar extends Activity {
private static int mYear;
public static int currentIndex = -1;
private static int mMonth;
public static int mDay;
public static String[][] a = new String[6][7];
private TextView date_today;
ImageButton last_month;
ImageButton next_month;

private ImageButton last_week;
private ImageButton next_week;

private TextView e00;
private TextView e01;
private TextView e02;
private TextView e03;
private TextView e04;
private TextView e05;
private TextView e06;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    date_today = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_today);
    last_month = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.last_month);
    next_month = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next_month);
    last_week = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.last_week);
    next_week = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next_week);

    e00 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e00);
    e01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e01);
    e02 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e02);
    e03 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e03);
    e04 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e04);
    e05 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e05);
    e06 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e06);

    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // / setListeners();

    last_month.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 1) {
                mYear -= 1;
                mMonth = 12;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                mMonth -= 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    next_month.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 12) {
                mYear += 1;
                mMonth = 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                mMonth += 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    last_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mMonth == 1) {
                mYear -= 1;
                mMonth = 12;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "last");
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                // mMonth -= 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "last");
                showOnScreen();
            }
        }
    });

    next_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mMonth == 12) {
                mYear += 1;
                mMonth = 1;
                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "next");
                showOnScreen();
            } else {
                if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == 4) {
                    HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = 4;
                    // mMonth += 1;
                }

                new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, "next");
                showOnScreen();
            }

        }
    });

    new ShowCalendar(mYear, mMonth);
    showOnScreen();

}

public void showOnScreen() {

    date_today.setText(mYear + "Years" + mMonth + "Month");
    e00.setText("" + a[0][0]);
    e01.setText("" + a[0][1]);
    e02.setText("" + a[0][2]);
    e03.setText("" + a[0][3]);
    e04.setText("" + a[0][4]);
    e05.setText("" + a[0][5]);
    e06.setText("" + a[0][6]);

}
 }





                 public class ShowCalendar {
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth){
    this.mYear = mYear;
    this.mMonth = mMonth;

    calculateMonthFirstday();
}


public int getmDay() {
    return mDay;
}


public void setmDay(int mDay) {
    this.mDay = mDay;
}


public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay, String time){
    this.mYear = mYear;
    this.mMonth = mMonth;
    if (time == "next"){
        HoyahCalendar.currentIndex++;
        if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == 5){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex--;
        }
        this.mDay = mDay + 7;
    } else if (time == "last"){
        HoyahCalendar.currentIndex--;
        if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == -1){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex++;
        }
        this.mDay = mDay - 7;
    }
    calculateMonthFirstday();
}

public void calculateMonthFirstday(){
    int month, first_day=0;
    if((mYear%4==0 && mYear%100!=0)||(mYear%400==0))
        month=1;
    else
        month=0;

    int y, y12, c, c12, m, d;
    y = mYear%100;
    y12 = (mYear-1)%100; //only for January and February
    c = mYear/100;
    c12 = (mYear-1)/100;
    m = mMonth;
    d = 1;

    switch(mMonth){
    case 1: {first_day = y12 + y12/4 +c12/4 - 2*c12 + 26*(13 + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 2: {first_day = y12 + y12/4 +c12/4 - 2*c12 + 26*(14 + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 4: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 5: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 6: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 7: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 8: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 9: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 10: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 11: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 12: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    }
    if(first_day<0)
        first_day = 7 - (Math.abs(first_day))%7;//first_day每月第一天星期几
    else
        first_day = first_day%7;

    switch(mMonth){
        case 1: {CalculateCalendar(1,first_day,31);break;}
        case 2: {CalculateCalendar(2,first_day,28+month);break;}
        case 3: {CalculateCalendar(3,first_day,31);break;}
        case 4: {CalculateCalendar(4,first_day,30);break;}
        case 5: {CalculateCalendar(5,first_day,31);break;}
        case 6: {CalculateCalendar(6,first_day,30);break;}
        case 7: {CalculateCalendar(7,first_day,31);break;}
        case 8: {CalculateCalendar(8,first_day,31);break;}
        case 9: {CalculateCalendar(9,first_day,30);break;}
        case 10:{CalculateCalendar(10,first_day,31);break;}
        case 11:{CalculateCalendar(11,first_day,30);break;}
        case 12:{CalculateCalendar(12,first_day,31);break;}
    }
}

public void CalculateCalendar(int month_no, int week_no, int month_days){

    int i, s, targetRow = 0;
    int currentDay;
    if (this.mDay == 0){
        currentDay= HoyahCalendar.mDay;     
    }else {
        currentDay = this.mDay;
    }
    //String[][] a = new String[6][7];
    for (i=0;i<week_no;i++)
        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = "";

    for(i=week_no; i<week_no + month_days; i++){
        s = i - week_no + 1;
        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = String.valueOf(s);
        if (s == currentDay && HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == -1){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = i/7;
        }
    } 
    for (i=0; i<7;i++){
        if (HoyahCalendar.a[HoyahCalendar.currentIndex][i] == null){
            HoyahCalendar.a[0][i] = "";
        }else{
            HoyahCalendar.a[0][i] =    
  HoyahCalendar.a[HoyahCalendar.currentIndex][i];
        }

    }
    for(i=week_no+month_days; i<42; i++)


        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = "";
}
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean "close application and start again"?

Comment: when i press back button go to mobile Hone screen when start again application is show last week dates not current week dats. when i  un install application and  install again is show current week dates n first screen

Comment: is maintain last view screen some where not show current week screen every time

Comment: how to refresh activity every time when open application?

Comment: how to refresh activity on start??

Comment: You "don't start again".  You application is in the background, then you bring it to the foreground and of course, the application is how you left it, unless Android needed memory and killed it.  I think you should learn about Android first before trying to build applications.  Hint.  `onResume()` is what you need.

Comment: i did  i used this   @Override
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     //Refresh here
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     finish();
     startActivity(intent);
 }

app not start is open close open close contiously

Comment: Of course it does, you finish the activity before you start the next one!  I'm going to be honest. Looking a your previous questions, you have no idea what you are doing.  You should go back to learning and complete some tutorials for basic apps.  You should also learn about the Activity life cycle and Intents.